# Duplicate Button Created in Android

Tags: android

Although, I have created single copy of button titled:: "Mark as Favourite" in the file `fragment_details.xml`, I am getting additional duplicate copy of the button in the UI.

Link to git-hub code::  https://github.com/iamakshit/popular-movies-app/tree/dev-android-stage-2

Snapshot of the UI having duplicate button:
[image]

Code for fragment_details.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="akshit.android.com.popularmovies.DetailsActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_details">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movie_poster1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/movie_poster1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/movie_poster"
            android:layout_height="270dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/movie_title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/user_rating" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/release_date" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mark as Favourite"
                android:id="@+id/fav_button" />

        </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >


    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/plot_summary" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Code of DetailsActivity.java

```
package akshit.android.com.popularmovies;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Log.i("DetailsActivity", "savedInstanceState is null");
            // During initial setup, plug in the details fragment.
            DetailsActivityFragment details = new DetailsActivityFragment();
            details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(
                    android.R.id.content, details).commit();
        }


        // For button

    }

    public static class DetailsActivityFragment extends Fragment {

        public static Movie movie;

        public DetailsActivityFragment() {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.i("DetailsActivity", "onCreateView called");

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);


            // The detail Activity called via intent.  Inspect the intent for forecast data.
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

            if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("movie")) {
                movie = (Movie) intent.getSerializableExtra("movie");
                Log.i("DetailsActivity", movie.title);

                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_title))
                        .setText("Title : "+movie.title);

                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.user_rating)).setText("User Rating : "+movie.userRating);

                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.plot_summary)).setText("Summary : "+movie.plotSummary);

                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.release_date)).setText("Release Date : "+movie.releaseDate);
                ImageView moviePoster = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);
                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(movie.posterPath).into(moviePoster);
                moviePoster.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            }

            return rootView;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your Logcat output

Comment: Post your fragment_details.xml code

Comment: your github codes are not up-to-date. there is no button in the xml file

Comment: Hi @Pooya kindly refer to the updated link

Comment: Hi @YasirTahir :: kindly refer to the fragment_details.xml

Comment: I can't see a problem here but there is maybe a problem in your java code

Comment: @Pooya added java code as well

Answer (score 1):

The issue is no longer coming after I removed this line from my activity_details.xml

```
<include layout="@layout/content_details" />
```

Code for content_details.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="akshit.android.com.popularmovies.DetailsActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_details" />
```